# How to execute pg_dump in PowerShell and redirect the output to a file

Tags: postgresql, powershell, database-connection, pg-dump

My goal is to have a ps1-script which consider different local postgreSQL instances to dump and restore several databases. The expected result is a folder with the dumped data and a logfile of the actions done, due to have control if everything went ok.

My hurdels:

- either I get no output of the actions done (script Run-01-*)
- the execution of the script hangs (script Run-02-*)
- pg_dump can't connect to the database (script Run-03-*)

Here are my results:

```
<#
  Run-01-pg_dump-POSTGRES-Powershell-excutes-OK.ps1

  NOTE: replace 'mypassword' and 'mydatabase' to your local settings
  dump the database 'mydatabase' to folder 'D:\Temp\01-DATABASE.Dump.OK'
  => works fine, BUT makes no output to have control whether everythings went correct
  => REASON: pg_dump.exe writes its actions to StandardError
#>
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start([System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]@{
    FileName               = 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe'
    Arguments              = @('-d', 'postgresql://postgres:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabase', '--no-owner', '--no-privileges', '-C','-c', '-b', '-EUTF-8', '-v', '-Fd', '-Z9', '-f', 'D:\Temp\01-DATABASE.Dump.OK')
    CreateNoWindow         = $true
    UseShellExecute        = $false
    RedirectStandardInput  = $false
    RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    RedirectStandardError  = $false
})
$output = $process.StandardOutput
$out = $output.ReadToEnd() # reads from stdout
$out
```

Now I tryed to capture StandardError.

```
<#
  Run-02-pg_dump-POSTGRES-Powershell-HANGS.ps1
  NOTE: replace 'mypassword' and 'mydatabase' to your local settings
  dump the database 'mydatabase' to folder 'D:\Temp\02-DATABASE.Dump.HANGS'
  => The execution of the script hangs. Nothing is written to the folder (is empty), no output of 'pg_dump'
  => the process has to be terminated by the windows "task managaer'
  => after termination, the pg_dump writes partly actions to the standardError
#>
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start([System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]@{
    FileName               = 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe'
    Arguments              = @('-d', 'postgresql://postgres:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabase', '--no-owner', '--no-privileges', '-C','-c', '-b', '-EUTF-8', '-v', '-Fd', '-Z9', '-f', 'D:\Temp\02-DATABASE.Dump.HANGS')
    CreateNoWindow         = $true
    UseShellExecute        = $false
    RedirectStandardInput  = $false
    RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    RedirectStandardError  = $true
})
$output = $process.StandardOutput
$stderror  = $process.StandardError
$out = $output.ReadToEnd() # reads from stdout
$out
$err = $stderror.ReadToEnd()  # reads from stderr
$err
```

Then I stumpled over the hint to do it with the commandlet 'Start-Process'.

```
<#
  Run-03-pg_dump-POSTGRES-Powershell-using-commandlet-Start-Process-CONNECTION-FAILS.ps1
  NOTE: replace 'mypassword' and 'mydatabase' to your local settings
  dump the database 'mydatabase' to folder 'D:\Temp\03-DATABASE.Dump.CONNECT-FAILS'
  => The execution of the script failes.
  => 03-pd_dump-error:
     log pg_dump: Fehler: Verbindung zur Datenbank »mydatabase« fehlgeschlagen: konnte Hostnamen »localhost« nicht in Adresse übersetzen: Unknown server error
#>
$processArguments = @('-d', 'postgresql://postgres:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabase', '--no-owner', '--no-privileges', '-C','-c', '-b', '-EUTF-8', '-v', '-Fd', '-Z9', '-f', 'D:\Temp\03-DATABASE.Dump.CONNECT-FAILS')
$processOptions = @{
    FilePath = 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe'
    ArgumentList = @($processArguments)
    RedirectStandardOutput = "d:\Temp\03-pd_dump-output.log"
    RedirectStandardError  = "d:\Temp\03-pd_dump-error.log"
    NoNewWindow = $false
    UseNewEnvironment = $true
}
Start-Process @processOptions -wait
```

This lead to another error (refer 03-pd_dump-error' in script header) which i can't understand, because the postgres URI for connection worked properly in 01 and 02, even in the following 04.

```
REM 
REM   Run-04-pg_dump-POSTGRES-commandline-OK.cmd
REM
REM   NOTE: replace 'mypassword' and 'mydatabase' to your local settings
REM   dump the database 'mydatabase' to folder 'D:\Temp\04-DATABASE.Dump.OK'
REM
REM   => works fine

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe" -d postgresql://postgres:mypasswordmypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabase --no-owner --no-privileges -C -c -b -EUTF-8 -v -Fd -Z9 -f D:\Temp\04-DATABASE.Dump.OK 2>>D:\Temp\04-pd_dump-error.log
```

I am using postgreSQL version 12 and 13 with the related pg_dump, pg_restore.

Any help, advice, hint to solve the problem would be highly appreciated.